# Archiving tables with foreign key constraints in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, archive

I'd like to get your thoughts on the approach to archiving data from a set of tables with foreign key constraints. Please find the tables details below.

booking (Table):ID (UUID),  created_date_time   updated_date_time   transaction_id (UUID)

transaction (Table):ID (UUID),  created_date_time   updated_date_time   booking_id (UUID)

transaction_event (Table):ID (UUID),    created_date_time   updated_date_time   transaction_id (UUID)

Record Count: booking (25,65,881), transaction(92,21,261), transaction_event(2,27,65,114)

Foreign Key Constraints:
Booking.transaction_id to Transaction.ID

Transaction.booking_id to Booking.ID

Transaction_Event.transaction_id to Transaction.ID

1* Booking Table (transaction_id) references to Transaction Table (ID).

2* Transaction Table (booking_id) references to Booking Table (ID).

3* Transaction_Event Table (transaction_id) references to Transaction Table (ID).

**Requirement** : Archive older than 6 months data to different Archive DB Server and purge the same data on Live tables.

**Issue** : created_date and updated_date is not same for the records in all the 3 reference tables. So, archiving data older than 6 months in all the 3 tables seems to be bit difficult.
Purging data older than 6 months is not an issue, because I am using the constraint ON DELETE CASCADE.

I have created a procedure which copies older than 6 months records in all the 3 tables from Live to Archive DB. Also created inner procedures which will check for any related records from all these 3 tables which are greater than remaining time. But it takes much time to complete.

NOTE: I need to configure Archive job to run every night to archive data older than 6 Months.

I'd be very grateful if someone has any other option to help me on this . Thank you.